# Шифрование хеш-функции и создание электронной цифровой подписи

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, вычислил хеш-значение для файла:

```
 public string ComputeSha1Checksum(string pathInFile)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathInFile))
        {
            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(fileData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            byte[] checkSum = sha.ComputeHash(fileData);
            string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

А теперь как хеш-значение записать в отдельный файл и затем зашифровать его с помощью алгоритма RSA? чтобы получилась электронная цифровая подпись и потом соединить с документом

Создание пары ключей я планирую сделать так:

```
cspp.KeyContainerName = keyName_for_sign; // keyName_for_sign это контейнер ключей
        rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
```

А открытый ключ я планирую записать в xml-файл, записать в файл только открытые параметры, экспоненту и модуль:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PubKeyFile_for_sign, false);
        sw.Write(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
        sw.Close();
```

А уже потом этот файл можно свободно размещать на любом ресурсе, то есть подпись сможет потом проверить любой желающий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Станартный `RSACryptoServiceProvider` умеет вычислять хэш и подписывать его:

```cs
byte [] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathInFile);

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte [] signature = rsaAlg.SignData(fileData , new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

File.WriteAllBytes(pathInFile + ".signature", signature);
```

В [MSDN по `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9tsc5d0z(v=vs.110).aspx) есть подробный пример с комментариями.

Кроме самого результата (подписи) вам понадобится еще как минимум где-то хранить public key, которым вы ее подписали - и передавать его проверяющему подпись по надежному каналу, желательно отдельно от подписанного документа.

Ну и сами по себе private key и public key должны быть сгенерированы до самого процесса подписывания, и должны где-то хранится.

В примере выше `RSACryptoServiceProvider` генерирует новую пару ключей при каждом создании. Вам же нужно заранее сгенерировать их. Ключи в строковом виде можно извлечь вызовом `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(bool includePrivateParameters)`. Импортировать извне - вызовом `RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString`.

Public key (результат вызова с `false`) - отдать тому, кто будет проверять подпись.

Private key (результат вызова с `true`) - не отдавать никому, хранить в надежном месте.

Если есть необходимость подписывать заранее вычисленный хэш, то достаточно заменить вызов `SignData` на `SignHash`:

```cs
SHA1Managed hash = new SHA1Managed(); // или SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
byte[] hashedData = hash.ComputeHash(fileData);

byte[] signature = rsaAlg.SignHash(hashedData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
```

Если для подписи нужно использовать сертификаты, лежащие в контейнере, или просто готовый объект `X509Certificate2`, то готовый `RSACryptoServiceProvider` , инициализированный нужными ключами, можно достать прямо из объекта сертификата. Цепочка вызвов будет примерно следующей:

```cs
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;

X509Certificate2 certificate = // поиск нужного сертификата в certificates

// при создании подписи 
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = 
    (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

// при проверке подписи
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKeyProvider = 
    (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
```

Comment: Я представил в вопросе как я планирую и подскажите, пожалуйста ещё, а потом контейнер ключей как связать с методом создания подписи?

Comment: @Andrey26rus дописал про готовый хэш и про работу с контейнерами.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста ещё, а проверку как можно сделать?

Comment: @Andrey26rus `VerifyData`/`VerifyHash`. в ответе есть ссылка на пример который генерирует ключи, подписывает, и потом проверяет.